# USB pendrive : A request for the USB device descriptor failed

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive

I have tried in several computers so it's a device problem.

It says: Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)

A request for the USB device descriptor failed.

Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)

Needless to say there is no drive letter associated to the device.

Is there any tools to troubleshot these kind of hardware problem ?? What is causing the problem ? Maybe I just need to tell windows it's a 4Gb pendrive :)

Comment: No. What you *should* do is get rid of it. USB flash drives are consumables. Get a new one.

Comment: Especially a 4gb drive that's worth about $2. Save yourself the hassle and hurl it into the trashcan.

Comment: That is probably what is going to happen, but still. What usually causes this problem, USB connector on the pendrive, the flash itself ?

Comment: The controller inside the flash drive is failing.